# Getting cookie value or getting data from DB?

Tags: java, database, cookies

Which of these operations require more time and resources? Getting cookie value or getting data from DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both serve a different purpose. *Cookies* are used to store preferences and are disposable in a sense that if they aren't available (like the client deleted them) the preferences switch to defaults.

*Database* on the other hand would store data that should persist through-out the application's life. For example, user login data. You can't save that as cookies for security reasons as well as that you may lose them any time.

*Cookies* can only save text whereas you can practically save anything in a *database* as binary objects.

Any preferences saved with *Cookies* would only take effect if the user uses the same browser that the cookies were stored on. So, *databases* are also more suited for any preferences that should be mobile.